# Bad Request in QuickBooks API production, works in sandbox

Tags: php, quickbooks

Today I tried to switch over development code to a limited-release production environment and immediately ran into issues.

The QuickBooks Accounting API works fine, however when it comes to payments I am able to accept them in sandbox mode but production returns "400 Bad Request"

I'm using my production API keys, I'm accessing the production API endpoints (api.intuit.com as opposed to sandbox.api.intuit.com), and I know the query I'm sending should be fine since it works in sandbox mode (unique Request-Id, amount, token, and currency provided in request body, proper content-type header, etc)

I also know my API key is fine since it works with the QuickBooks Accounting API. I am able to create a customer and create an invoice, but when I attempt to collect payment on the invoice it throws up on me.

What could be going wrong? I can post any code snippets or errors required. I'm using Laravel 5.2 with a phpOauthLib wrapper written by lusitanian.

The code I'm using:

```
$oauth = OAuth::consumer('QuickBooks');
$oauth_token = unserialize(file_get_contents(storage_path("tokens/oauth.token")));
$storage = $oauth->getStorage();
$storage->storeAccessToken('QuickBooks', $oauth_token['access_token']);
$member = Member::find(Request::get('id'));
$query = urlencode("select * from customer where displayname = '" . $member->first_name . " " . $member->last_name . "'");
$result = json_decode($oauth->request("/v3/company/" . $oauth_token['company_id'] . "/query?query=" . $query, "GET"));
$donor = null;
if( !property_exists( $result->QueryResponse, 'Customer' ) ) {
    $donor = $oauth->request("/v3/company/" . $oauth_token['company_id'] . "/customer", "POST", json_encode([
        'DisplayName' => $member->first_name . " " . $member->last_name
    ]), array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
} else {
    $donor = $result->QueryResponse->Customer[0];
}
$pledge = $oauth->request("/v3/company/" . $oauth_token['company_id'] . "/invoice", "POST", json_encode([
    'Line' => [
        [
            'Amount' => '25.00',
            'DetailType' => 'SalesItemLineDetail',
            'SalesItemLineDetail' => [
                'ItemRef' => [
                    'value' => '21'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'CustomerRef' => [
        'value' => $donor->Id
    ]
]), array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
$pledge = json_decode( $pledge )->Invoice;
$guid = GUID();
/************** THIS IS THE LINE THAT FAILS: ***************/
$capture = $oauth->request("https://api.intuit.com/quickbooks/v4/payments/charges", "POST", json_encode([
    'amount' => $amount,
    'token' => Request::get('token'),
    'currency' => "USD"
]), ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Request-Id' => $guid]);
$capture = json_decode( $capture );
$payment = $oauth->request("/v3/company/" . $oauth_token['company_id'] . "/payment", "POST", json_encode([
    'CustomerRef' => [
        'value' => $donor->Id,
        'name' => $donor->DisplayName
    ],
    'TotalAmt' => $capture->amount,
    'Line' => [
        [
            'Amount' => $capture->amount,
            'LinkedTxn' => [
                [
                    'TxnId' => $pledge->Id,
                    'TxnType' => 'Invoice'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]), ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
```

Again, this code worked perfectly with the sandbox API, but now it fails. Tonight I'll see what I can do to get the HTTP transaction (request and response)

Comment: Post your code. Post the HTTP request you're sending. Post the HTTP response you're getting back. There is nothing anyone can do to help you without this very basic information.

Comment: Not technically true -- since I indicated that the code worked perfectly using the sandbox API, and that my API key worked perfectly with the accounting API. Regardless, I'll go pull my code and see what I can do to pull the HTTP requests being sent (the library generates the requests and I don't have a proxy set up to easily capture requests from the dev server, so I'll have to work something out to grab the actual bytes being transferred)

Comment: The issue is that there are about 5000 different things that can cause a 400 Bad Request error to come back from Intuit's services. If you look  at the raw HTTP response, usually you'll get back a more specific error in the actual body of the response. Without seeing the request and the response though, it's going to be REALLY, *really* hard for anyone to give you much more information.

Comment: Additionally, lots of those 400 Bad Request errors are not necessarily protocol related, but instead are data related. e.g. You might be referring to an Id value of an object one QBO account has... that the other QBO account doesn't. A 400 error will be thrown in that case. If you look at the raw HTTP response it'll tell you more specifically that that is the problem. Not trying to be difficult here, just trying to help. Troubleshooting is much MUCH easier if you have the HTTP request/response.